# postgresql - Advance replication slot as part of a transaction

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-13

Let me illustrate my use-case, I have a Python middleware doing this data transformation on the top of a postgresql replication slot, I would like to leverage Postgresql transactional capabilities.
I would like to "listen" to the replication slot Y and at the same time make some INSERTs to a table X not belonging in the publication of the replication slot Y.

I would like to know whether it is possible to "advance" the replication slot within a transaction containing the INSERTs to the table X.

From a quick research I found out that I can:

- use pg_logical_slot_get_changes to advance the replication slot, what I do not understand is how pg_logical_slot_get_changes behaves within a transaction. Can I assume that if I have a transaction failing containing pg_logical_slot_get_changes that will not affect my replication slot offset? I have a hunch this is the case.
- I found out that via psycopg2 I can use direclty the replication protocol directly and then acknowledge the receipt of a specific "replication message". I guess the question I have is similar to the previous one, whether the acknowledgement (via send_feedback) to specific messages can be put in a transaction so that if the transaction does not commit successfuly the acknowledgement is not "committed" in that sense.